# Reading annotations in Calibre

Tags: calibre, annotations, display

I have installed the [Annotations plugin](https://github.com/davidfor/calibre-annotations) for Calibre.

I have added an annotated ebook from my Kobo Aura H2O device to my Calibre library. Then I imported annotations from the device and Calibre said that it had added them as comments.

How can I display these comments in Calibre's ebook reader pane?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can't see them in the reader pane.
You'll find the annotations at:
Edit Metadata > Custom medata tab > Annotations

(Presuming you created a custom column called 'Annotations', which is the default name suggested by the plugin.)

Comment: The annotation display has now moved to "View → Browse annotations". Still a list display, not part of the e-book reader.